# How can I make my DIV so that it behaves like an address link

Tags: html, css

I have a DIV square containing the word "Next". I would like to have the DIV background color change when I hover over it and have it take me to a link when I click on it. Can I do this without using Javascript? I don't just want to use a link as I guess for that then it would only work if I go above "next".

Thank you very much for advance helping.

Comment: You can do the hover visual with `div:hover{...}` but the click will require JS.

Comment: "have it take me to a link when I click on it" means only clicking on it brings you to the actual link?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inevitably we have to ask: why not ***make*** it a hyperlink? If it quacks like a duck and looks like a duck, it should really be a duck.

You can handle the hovering effect with a simple `:hover` rule in your stylesheet (e.g., `div.whatever:hover { color: red; }`), but you can't instill an element with functionality like going to a new page without the use of JavaScript.

Comment: The DIV is large and the word "Next" is small. I would like a user clicking anywhere in the DIV to be able to make it go to the link. Also I want to change the DIV color. I am not sure. Can I do all this with a link? Now my DIV has a gradient. Can I make that also change when I hover. Thanks you very much.

Comment: @Beth You could set `display: inline-block;` on that link and use padding to make the clickable area bigger. That's one solution, there are many more (all requiring `display: inline-block;` or `display: block;`)

Comment: Generally, any question of "how I want this to look" can be resolved with stylesheets. Using a different element in your HTML doesn't solve any problems, and often (as in this case) creates new ones. As @Arjan suggests, you can make an element "bigger" either by specifying `width` and `height` or by specifying `margin` and `padding`.

Comment: Hello, I tried using an <a>. It does work fine but then I notice that my cursor does not change to a pointer like when I go over a button when inside of the <a>. Any ideas? Posting this comment in two place. Hope that's allowed.

Comment: I suspect you used `margin` which adds space OUTSIDE the element (i.e., between that element and any adjacent elements). Use `padding` when you want the space to be INSIDE the element.

Comment: I'll open up another question. That way I can show my code. Thanks

Comment: @Beth - You can use `cursor: default;` to set your cursor to an arrow.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML4(and to the best of my knowledge) HTML5 you can't do this. I heard they are planning on doing it in XHTML2 but that's not out yet.

You could simply use the `<a>` element like a `<div>` just give it a class, for example `NextLink` and then you can do things in CSS to make it look and act like a div:

```
.NextLink {
    display:block;
}
.NextLink:hover {
    background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by having a hyperlink within the DIV with display:block:

```
<style>
#next:hover { background-color:red; }
#next a { display:block; }
</style>

<div id="next">
    <a href="#">Next</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Sort of... but the hyperlink would not automatically fill the entire height. Better is to just style the `<a>` as desired and not even worry about the `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can't really do that without javascript--or at least it wouldn't be worth trying, in my opinion.  The best approach would be to style the `a` tag.  Something like this:

```
a {padding:10px;border:solid 1px #000;}
a:HOVER {background-color:yellow;}
```